# How to numerically solve a system with two matrices in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, system

I'm trying to numerically find the solution to `A*cos x +B*sin x = C` where A and B are two known square matrices of the same size (for example 100x100), and C is a known vector (100x1).
Without the second term (i.e. with a single matrix), I will use Jacobi or Gauss-Seidel to solve this problem and get x but here, I don't see how to proceed to solve this problem in Matlab.
May be, it would be useful to solve the problem as : `A*X + B*sqrt(1-X^2) = C`.

I would greatly appreciate any help, ideas or advices
Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem `A*X + B*Y = C` can be rewritten as `[A,B]*[X;Y] = C`,  but that doesn’t allow you to include the known non-linear relationship between `X` and `Y = sqrt(1-X^2)`. So the optimization procedure in the answer below is likely the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you could use [`fsolve`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) like this (`c` and `X` are vectors):

```matlab
A = ones(2,2);
B = ones(2,2);
c = ones(2,1);

% initial point
x0 = ones(length(A), 1);
% call to fsolve
sol = fsolve(@(x) A * cos(x) + B*sin(x) - c, x0);
```

Here, we solve the nonlinear equation system `F(x) = 0` with `F: R^N -> R^N` and `F(x) = A * cos(x) + B*sin(x) - c`.

Only for the sake of completeness, here's my previous answer, i.e. how one could do it in case `C` and `X` are matrices instead of vectors:

```matlab
A = ones(2,2);
B = ones(2,2);
C = ones(2,2);

% initial point
x0 = ones(numel(A), 1);

% call to fsolve
fsolve(@(x) fun(x, A, B, C), x0)


function [y] = fun(x, A, B, C)
    % Transform the input vector x into a matrix
    X = reshape(x, size(A));
    % Evaluate the matrix equation
    Y = A * cos(X) + B*sin(X) - C;
    % flatten the matrix Y to a row vector y
    y = reshape(Y, [], 1);
end
```

Here, the idea is to transform the matrix equation system `F: R^(N x N) -> R^(N x N)` into a equivalent nonlinear system `F: R^(N*N) -> R^(N*N)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, effectively the use of fsolve could be the best option. However, just to be sure to well understand your example: C is a vector of the same size of cos x, so C = ones (2,1); and finally after using fsolve, what are the given solutions (corresponding to y) the vector X ?

Comment: @Acosia Oops, I totally missed that C is a vector instead of a matrix. So I guess `x` is a vector, too, right? In this case, the situation is much easier, and I'll edit my answer accordingly. My answer assumed that `C` and `X` are matrices.

Comment: Exactly, A and B are two matrices of the same size, and x and C are two vectors of the same size (A, B, C are know). I greatly appreciate your help. Is there any problem to use fsolve to get the x vector from matrices with great size 100 x 100 or not ?

Comment: @Acosia I edited my answer. The runtime of `fsolve` heavily depends on the runtime needed to evaluate the function `F`. In your case, `F` only needs to compute two matrix-vector products which are computationally cheap compared to matrix-multiplications. Here, even 10000x10000 matrices shouldn't be a problem on modern hardware. :-)